# Range slider with arbitrary snap points

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have implemented the [jQuery range slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) on a webpage I am building, but it does not seem to be possible to make it snap to specific non-uniformly distributed values. Does any one know if this is possible with the jQuery slider or if there is an alternate I can use?

As a more concrete example, say I have a range from 0 to 100, and I have an array like `[0, 7, 32, 61, 67, 90, 100]`. I want the range slider to only be able to select the values in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`slide` callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) to limit the allowed positions:

> Triggered on every mouse move during slide. The value provided in the event as `ui.value` represents the value that the handle will have as a result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous value.

So you'd just need something like this:

```
var allowed = { 0: true, 7: true, /*...*/ 100: true };
$("#slider").slider({
    //...
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if(!allowed[ui.value])
            return false;
    }
});
```

You could also use an array for `allowed` and `return false` when `allowed.indexOf(ui.value)` is negative; I think using an object reads better.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eRtBa/